# Do AntMiners comply with FCC Part 15?

Tags: safety, antminer

Do AntMiners comply with [Part 15](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_47_CFR_Part_15) of the U.S. Federal Communication Commission's rules and regulations?

I tagged this question with "safety" because implicit in my question is what percentage of watts going into an AntMiner get converted to RF interference. If it's a lot, it could be a safety issue, especially since the cases of many AntMiners (e.g., S5s) are open and thus do not act as Faraday cages.

Comment: Why is this tagged `safety`? [Part 15](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_47_CFR_Part_15) regulates electronic interference.

Comment: @NickODell See ¶2 that I added to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. On their [sales listing](https://www.bitmaintech.com/productDetail.htm?pid=00020141223034607777DtzESHvI06C9) they note specifically that they have passed FCC and CE approval, and their products bear the markings for this accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe they are shooting straight - I have noticed strong emissions in the UHF and VHF ranges.

Comment: That is why semiconductor devices should be shielded - I am guessing they are intended to be arranged in a metallic case to keep emissions down. I have also had issues with one miner's spurious emissions disconnecting the adjacent miner's wifi by destroying the signal to noise ratio.

Comment: How strong of emissions, and how did you measure them?